# Show that $\int_R f=0$ if $f(x)=0$, for every $x \in int(R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, real-numbers

This is my first time using Stack Exchange. I hope that everyone is doing great. I'd really appreciate some help with the second part of this problem (proving that $\int_R f=0$). I've already proved that $f$ is integrable.

The problems goes like this. Let $f\colon R \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function such that $f(x)=0$, for every $x \in int(R)$. Show that $f$ is integrable over $R$ and $\int_R f=0$.

We're assuming that $R$ is an $n$-rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $\epsilon>0$ is a positive number. Given that $f$ is bounded in $R$ then there exists $N>0$ such that $\vert f(x) \rvert\leq N$.

We can select a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $R$ such that $\mathcal{A}=\{R_1,R_2,...,R_n\}$ is the family of all rectangles in $R$ induced by $\mathcal{P}$. From this family $\mathcal{A}$ we ask that the subfamily $\mathcal{A'}=\{R_i \in \mathcal{A}:R_i \cap Fr(R) \neq \varnothing\}\subset\mathcal{A}$ satisfies that

\begin{align*}\sum_{R_i \in \mathcal{A'}}<\frac{\displaystyle \epsilon}{\displaystyle 2N}.\end{align*}

If we do this, we will eventually get that

\begin{align*}U(f,\mathcal{P})-L(f.\mathcal{P})<\epsilon\end{align*}

However, I'm still unsure of how to prove the second part. I'm not sure if it can be proven by making the partition $\mathcal{P}$ tend to infinite. In that way, we would reduce the size of the rectangles $R_i$ that intersects with $Fr(R)$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What if $R=(\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q)\cap[0,1]$? Then the interior is empty, so the assumption that $f=0$ on the interior is vacuously true. Now let $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in R$. Or was the assumption that $R$ is a rectangle part of the premises and not a special case considered for your proof?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos $R$ should be an $n$-rectangle.